# using constant filepointer to rewind and fscanf

Tags: c, warnings

I am trying to use a const FILE *fp to rewind, fscanf and etc. the usual stuff but I run into c4090 error and I am not quite understanding it.

```
int search(const FILE *fp, int patt) {
   if (fp != NULL) {
     rewind(fp) //Getting c4090 warning
     //other statements
   }
}
```

This seems like a basic question and I tried searching for a bit and microsoft manual is mostly what I've got and I don't really understand what they are implying

Comment: `rewind` modifies the `FILE` struct, so it doesn't take a `const FILE *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This warning can be caused when a pointer to a const or volatile item is assigned to a pointer not declared as pointing to const or volatile."

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k77bkb8d.aspx

Try:

```
int search(FILE *fp, int patt) {
    if (fp != NULL) {
     rewind(fp) //No c4090 warning, Because we can change fp
     //other statements
    }
}
```